# How to CSS border spacing (or) padding background image separately?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, navigation, background-image

My Wordpress (TwentyTwelve) nav menu works great, but with design I would like to do this, but can't ;

- no background to the navigation (clear, we see page background) = done
- li a border-right 1px solid = done
- li a hover background image, no repeat, bottom center = done

So the problem is : my bg image is way too close to my nav text... but if I add padding or line-height, then the border-right gets too long.

So How can I add spacing under my nav text, so that my bg image (hover) gets lower, but without the right-border line getting longer ?

See my CSS code if it helps

`

```
.main-navigation li a {
color: #fff;
line-height: 1.0;
text-transform: uppercase;
white-space: nowrap;
    background:;
padding:0 15px 10px 15px; 
margin:0;
border-right:#8fbf3d 1px solid;
}

.main-navigation li a:hover {
color: #fff;
background:url('http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/myown/images/bg-nav-hover.png') no-repeat bottom center;
}

.main-navigation .current-menu-item > a,
.main-navigation .current-menu-ancestor > a,
.main-navigation .current_page_item > a,
.main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a {
color: #8fbf3d;
font-weight: bold;
background:url('http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/myown/images/bg-nav-hover.png') no-repeat bottom center;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

still not found that magic way to do this... but I found an alternative that could work

- deleted the right-border
- added a background image looking like a right-border line (but its a jpeg) and put it align right
- added my previous padding-bottom

work!

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS;

```
background-position: 10px 10px;
```

for example being X and Y, you could also do it percentual.

Also you can do;

```
background-position: center center;
```

or

```
background-position: right top;
```

for example.

EDIT------
I think you have wrong the order instead of bottom center use center bottom, try;

```
background:url('http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/myown/images/bg-nav-hover.png') no-repeat center bottom;
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesnt work on this example. Here is my CSS code
- right border always visible
- bottom bg image just visible on Hover and on Current
...i have added my css code above

Comment: @revv86 that CSS code is quite weird. Anyway Im speaking about the background property not the border, as I understood your question was about that

Comment: sorry, it saved my comment too quikly. See css code above, the good one, thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks, i did change to center bottom, (was already working in my Chrome). Any idea for my question/problem ? :-)

Comment: it should be working by now!, i mean, you where placing an invalid x coordinate(bottom) so was being ignored, couldnt you solve it with this?

Comment: not solve, still looking how to add spacing between nav text and hover gb image, without getting the right border longer